# Issue installing Python module on OSX 10.6 and with gcc 4.0 and 4.2

Tags: python

I run sudo python setup.py install to install the Mongrel2 Python support, but it fails with this :-

```
> Installed
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-
> packages/m2py-1.0beta7-py2.7.egg
> Processing dependencies for
> m2py==1.0beta7 Searching for storm
> Reading
> http://pypi.python.org/simple/storm/
> Reading https://storm.canonical.com
> Reading
> https://launchpad.net/storm/+download
> Best match: storm 0.18 Downloading
> http://launchpad.net/storm/trunk/0.18/+download/storm-0.18.tar.bz2
> Processing storm-0.18.tar.bz2 Running
> storm-0.18/setup.py -q bdist_egg
> --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-SLExAI/storm-0.18/egg-dist-tmp-kQRcFq In file included from
> /usr/include/architecture/i386/math.h:626,
>                from /usr/include/math.h:28,
>                from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyport.h:312,
>                from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:58,
>                from storm/cextensions.c:23:
> /usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:108:14:
> warning: #warning Building for Intel
> with Mac OS X Deployment Target < 10.4
> is invalid.
> /usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.0.1/as:
> assembler
> (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as
> or
> /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as)
> for architecture ppc not installed
> Installed assemblers are:
> /usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as
> for architecture x86_64
> /usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as
> for architecture i386 lipo: can't open
> input file: /var/tmp//ccByYCOo.out (No
> such file or directory) error: Setup
> script exited with error: command
> 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1.
```

I then re-ran it with sudo CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 python setup.py install, but with the same results.

I have Python 2.7.1 installed and am running on OSX 10.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you have installed Xcode 4 and you've installed a traditional 32-bit-only, backward-compatible Python 2.7.1, possibly from python.org.  Unfortunately, the two don't mix well; that Python was built with and requires Xcode 3.  You can either backup to Xcode 3 or, better, install a [64-bit/32-bit Python 2.7.x from here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.2/) (2.7.2 was just released, BTW).

Comment: You're welcome.  By the way, I've updated the current python.org download pages to include a footnote about Xcode 3 vs Xcode 4.